# Error in Azure Terraform module for managing group budgets

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, cost-management

"While generating the Terraform plan, I encountered the following error:

```
Error: Module is incompatible with count, for_each, and depends_on

   on main.tf line 3, in module "consumption-budget-management-group":
   3:   for_each                      = var.cbmg  
 
 The module within a module consumption-budget-management-group is considered a legacy module, and it contains its own local provider configurations. Therefore, it cannot accept the count, for_each, or depends_on arguments.

If you also control the module "../../../../terraform-module/consumption-budget-management-group", consider
updating this module to instead expect provider configurations to be passed by its caller.
```

I attempted to resolve the issue by changing the Terraform version, but that did not work. Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated."

Comment: Please share the code you tried that causing the error @Ganesh